# Why the browser doesn't see my module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
ECMAScript 6

I learn JavaScript and read the *Understanding ECMAScript 6* book. ECMAScript 6 defines the *module* conception.

I wrote couple js-files and attached them into my html file. One of them is script and other is the module. But Google Chrome doesn't see my js-module. Why does it happen?

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <script src='./js/module.js' type='module'></script>
    <script src='./js/script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my script:

```
/* ECMAScript 6
 * ./js/script.js
 */

function scriptFunction(){
    console.log('I am script function!');
}
```

This is my module:

```
/* ECMAScript 6
 * ./js/module.js
 */

function internalFunction(){
    console.log('I am internal!');
}

export function exportedFunction(){
    console.log('I am exported!');
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: The fact there is an export in module doesn't mean that it exports to global scope. In fact, the idea of exporting to global defies the purpose of modules.

Comment: I don't think modules are yet supported in browsers. If I am reading this correctly it won't be available till chrome 60.... https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232

Comment: I think you're going to have to use babel to transpile your code first is you are using es6/es2015  ~ don't they explain that in the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are not yet supported by most browsers. Safari 10.1 implements them. In Chrome Canary you need to enable support as explained by @SkinnyJ.

But still you'll have to fix some issues in your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <script src='./js/module.js' type='module'></script>
    <script src='./js/script.js' type='module'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
/* ECMAScript 6
 * ./js/module.js
 */

function internalFunction() {
    console.log("I am internal!");
}

export function exportedFunction() {
    internalFunction();
    console.log("I am exported!");
}
```

```js
/* ECMAScript 6
 * ./js/script.js
 */

import {exportedFunction} from "./module.js";

function scriptFunction() {
    console.log("I am script function!");
}
scriptFunction();
exportedFunction();
```

This works in Safari 10.1 and Chrome Canary with chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features enabled.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 modules are currently available in [Chrome Canary](https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7) behind the "Experimental Web Platform" flag. They are not available in "stable" Chrome.